# Java create instances of classes on the fly

Tags: java, class

I am making a small card game. In this game a new player is an instance of a class, AIPlayer or HumanPlayer which extends a general player class.

Currently to generate players I have the following code:

```
private List<Player> players;

HumanPlayer playerA = new HumanPlayer("playerA");
playerA.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
players.add(playerA);

AIPlayer playerB = new AIPlayer("playerB");
playerB.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
players.add(playerB);

AIPlayer playerC = new AIPlayer("playerC");
playerC.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
players.add(playerC);

HumanPlayer playerD = new HumanPlayer("playerD");
playerD.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
players.add(playerD);
```

Is it possible to dynamically generate these classes?
Could I do something like iterating over all the elements of a linkedlist with a player name and a boolean to indicate if their are AI or Human and generate an instance of a class for them then. If so, how?

Edit: to make it clearer, I'm looking if something like this is possible:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
player i = new Player("i");
i.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
players.add(i); }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamically generate these classes*? You could check the actual objects within your `List<Player>` via `instanceof` and react accordingly, but this is (at least from my point of view) an unelegant solution. Why do you need to know whether the `Player` is an `AIPlayer` or a `HumanPlayer`? Maybe your design is flawed.

Comment: Create a method `addPlayer(String name)`.

Comment: AIPlayer and HumanPlayer have different functions. I also find it something strange to do but I wondered if it's possible.

Comment: @Turing85 Why not it's illegal, with the factory pattern v.1 it's legal.

Comment: @HansvanderLaan Maybe this is the problem. From an abstract point of view, an `AIPlayer` and a `HumanPlayer` should have the same (basic) functionalities (e.g. some `makeMove`-Method). For the game, it should probably totally transparent whether an AI or a human is making a move.

Comment: @RomanC sorry? I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
class Player {

    String name;
    Type type;

    public Player(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

Player[] playersList = { new Player("playerA", Type.HUMAN), new Player("playerB", Type.AI)};
for (Player player: playersList) {
    if (player.type == Type.AI) {
            AIPlayer aiPlayer = AIPlayer.class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(player.name);
            aiPlayer.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
            players.add(aiPlayer);                                    }
    else {
            HumanPlayer humanPlayer = HumanPlayer.class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(player.name);
            humanPlayer.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
            players.add(humanPlayer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you ever use an array instead of a `List` if you already call your attribute `playerList`? Furhtermore, in OP there are more than two players.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How would I, in the code you propose, add an Observer to the newly generated player? That's the main issue I am facing.

Comment: Just put the `addObserver`method below the `if` in the loop.

Comment: @Turing85 you're right about the naming: I noticed that the OP used a variable named "players" after I wrote my code, so I renamed it on the fly without noticing the inconsistency. For the players, I think the OP can do some copy&paste.. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This not answer your question, but, maybe solve your problem:

```
private List<Player> players;

public void createPlayerByName(String name, Class type) {
  Player player = type.equals(HumanPlayer) ? new HumanPlayer(name) : new IAPlayer(name);
  player.addObserver(gameModelObserver);
  players.add(player);
}

public void createHumanPlayerByName(String name) {
  createPlayerByName(name, HumanPlayer.class);
}

public void createIAPlayerByName(String name) {
  createPlayerByName(name, AIPlayer.class);
}
```

So with your list you just need to do this:

```
for (String name : humanNameList) {
  createHumanPlayerByName(name);
}

for (String name : aiNameList) {
  createAIPlayerByName(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It could solve my problem this way. I'm still curious if what I'm asking is possible tho :)

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended, to create by `Player player = AIPlayer.class.newInstance();` because it won't call the constructor, just generate the Object.

Comment: @Sertage "*[...] because it won't call the constructor.*" In Java, you cannot create objects without calling some constructor. The [Javadoc for `newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) specifically says "*[...] that this method propagates any exception thrown by the **nullary constructor**, including a checked exception*" (it is called via reflection). However, it is better to use [`Constructors.newInstance(Object ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: @Turing85 sorry, you are right. I had a different idea about how it works. Thanks :)